# How is pywraplp SAT different from CP-SAT?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

In ortools if you have only 0-1 variables you can either use CP-SAT from

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
```

or you can use

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SAT')
```

Are these solvers the same and if not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pywraplp supports linear equations/inequations with floating point coefficients.

CP-SAT is integral only, but support much more constraints (quadratic scheduling, routing...) in addition to linear constraints.
CP-SAT does support floating point coefficients for the objective.

pywraplp with the SAT backend scales all coefficients to achieve linear constraints that only have integral coefficients, then calls the CP-SAT solver.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really informative and helpful.